# How to show dotCover coverage in new VS2017-type csproj project

Tags: resharper, code-coverage, visual-studio-2017, csproj, dotcover

I have a solution that contains 3 projects.

- **PROJECT 1**
  A VS2017-style .csproj project that has multitargetting to `net45` and `netstandard1.1`.
- **PROJECTS 2 and 3**
  Two traditional VS2015-style .csproj test projects, targetting `net45`, using NUnit.

The reason for projects 2 and 3 not to be new-style is because it seems that right now ReSharper does not recognize these assemblies for running tests. It does find the tests just fine on old-style projects targeting any .NET framewory (full) or `netcore` assemblies, though.

Using that structure, I can run all my tests all right with the unit test window from dotCover, but when trying to gather coverage results it returns all green for the old-style projects, and all empty for the new-style project.

Coverage tree shows 0% coverage for my new-style project. Gutter highlighting and code highlighting all show in grey, although the tests have run successfully. All of them.

I've tried building in Debug mode, and setting specific values for "Platform" and "Framework" on the Unit Test Sessions window of ReSharper to no avail.

Is this something I'm doing wrong, or are we waiting for an update from ReSharper to fix this?

I am using:

- NUnit 2.6.4 (because my unit test projects target `net45`)
- Moq 4.5.28
- ReSharper Ultimate 2017.1.2 with dotCover 2017.1.2 (says it's up to date at the time of writing).
- Visual Studio Professional 2017 15.2 (26430.12)
- I have installed all target frameworks until 4.7.02053
- The projects I'm talking about are in C#

Comment: Can you try to set the property `<DebugType>Full</DebugType>` in your library project?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. And setting `<DebugType>Full</DebugType>` solved it for me as mentions by Martin